# Problem with while loop that does not finish and stays in an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement, while-loop

In this code I don't understand why when wanting to change the parameter of the while loop, that is, that the flag is different and the user enters "do not buy", it doesn't finish but stays in an infinite loop... I have tried multiple ways and I can't get the loop to finish...

```
let promotion = alert('Free shipping for purchases over $100,000')

class Product{
    constructor(name, price, id){
        this.name = name.toUpperCase();
        this.price = parseFloat(price);
        this.id = id;
    }
    discount(){
        this.price = this.price * 0.8;
    }
}

const products = []
products.push(new Product('green tea', '24500', 1));
products.push(new Product('black tea', '14800', 2));
products.push(new Product('relaxnat tea', ' 14800', 3));
products.push(new Product('biotin', '61000', 4));

for(const product of products ){
    product.discount();
}
console.log(products);

let flag = parseInt(prompt('enter the id of your product and if you do not want any of our products enter do not buy'));

function notShow(signal){
    alert(signal)
}

while(flag != 'do not buy'){
      if(flag === 1){
          products.find((el) => {
              if(el.id === 1){
                  notShow( el.name + ' ' + el.price);
              }
          })
      } else if(flag === 2){
          products.find((el) => {
              if(el.id === 2){
                  notShow( el.name + ' ' + el.price);
              }
          })
      } else if(flag === 3){
          products.find((el) => {
              if(el.id === 3){
                  notShow( el.name + ' ' + el.price);
              }
          })
      } else if(flag === 4){
          products.find((el) => {
              if(el.id === 4){
                  notShow( el.name + ' ' + el.price);
              }
          })
      }else if(flag != 1 ||2 ||3 ||4 ){
          notShow('We are sorry for not fulfilling your purchase wish');
      }
  flag = parseInt(prompt('enter the id of your product and if you do not want any of our products enter do not buy'));
}
```

Comment: Your while loop compares `flag` to a string (with the wrong comparator, use `!==` for that, not `!=`) but nowhere in your code will it ever take on that value. Look at all the lines where you have `flag = ...` and look at what value you are assigning. Also, note that your `else if(flag != 1 ||2 ||3 ||4 )` is just `else`. You _already_ ruled out that it's 1, 2, 3, or 4 because you already have if statements that cover those situations. Except you also have a bug there: `if (flag !==1 || 2)` is true, because that code does _not_ say `if flag not equal 1 or flag not equal 2).

Comment: OP is using `prompt` value will be provided by user

Comment: No they aren't. They're using `parseInt`, which happens to be provided a value using prompt.

Comment: Good point. Other than that `flag != 1 ||2 ||3 ||4` will always evaluate to `true` since there is missing `flag == ` after each `||`

Comment: the calculated value of the `1 ||2 ||3 ||4` expression is `1`, so your `if (flag != 1 ||2 ||3 ||4 )` test is equivalent to doing `if (flag != 1 )`

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt()` is changing whatever the user enters into a number, so `flag` will never == 'do not buy'.